# Literature Request: Abstract albegra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Any of y'all have any suggestions on books/websites that give an intuitive intro to abstract algebra/basic algebraic structures?

Comment: We *do* have good suggestions. You should have looked for them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure you have had some type of proofs course. Discrete Math as well. Frequently you get both of those in the same course. Also linear algebra would be a recommended prereq but nonessential.

Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian (good intro and gets most of the main concepts)

Algebra by Sepanski (more detailed but assumes a slightly more competent/mathematically mature reader)